# Why can't I install shell extensions in vista anymore?

Tags: windows-vista, troubleshooting, shell-extensions

I think my pc is in a strange state. I can't seem to install any shell extensions (though I was able to at one point). Does anyone why this could be? Is there anything I can do to verify new extensions can be installed?

When installing either of the 2 below it appears to work but the shell remains the same:

- [Hashtab](http://beeblebrox.org/)
- [CmdOpen](http://code.kliu.org/cmdopen/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)** to check whether the new extensions are disabled.

Comment: Cool tool! Both shell extensions were disabled. Is there anything that would make this the default action when installing extensions? I'd like to disable that if its the case.

Comment: beats me what went wrong, but i had the problem before, so ShellExView is handy to have around. :)